# tar.xz extracting error "xz: (stdin): File format not recognized"

Tags: tar, ubuntu-mate

I am trying to extract a `.tar.xz` file on my Ubuntu Mate computer. No matter what I do, I get this error:

```
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I have done the following (although my repeated attempts to circumvent the error may highlight my ignorance):

```
tar xf file.tar.xz
```

Then,

```
unxz file.tar.xz #results in file.tar
```

That time, I got this similar error:

```
unxz: file.tar.xz: File format not recognized
```

Then, I did this:

```
tar -xJf file.tar.xz
```

Etcetera...

I tried updating/installing tar and xz-utils using

```
sudo apt-get install xz-utils
```

for `x-utils`, and

```
sudo apt-get install tar
```

for `tar`. They both updated/installed successfully, but when I did the above things again, I got the same errors.

EDIT ONE

When I use:

```
file file.tar.xz
```

I get

```
file.tar.xz: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
```

When I try to open it with Engrampa using

```
engrampa file.tar.xz
```

I get the same error mentioned above.

I am running Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on the Raspberry Pi 3.

The output of

```
apt list xz-utils
```

is

```
Listing... Done
xz-utils/xenial,now 5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2 armhf [installed]
```

The output of

```
xz --version
```

is

```
xz (XZ Utils) 5.1.0alpha
liblzma 5.1.0alpha
```

The output of

```
tar --version
```

is

```
tar (GNU tar) 1.28
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Liscense GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/lisenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
```

I obtained the file (pepper-flash-v.20.0.0.228r1.tar.xz) by using the command line

```
wget http://dl.free.fr/qVkzvqSiB -O pepper-flash-v20.0.0.228-r1.tar.xz
```

EDIT TWO

Thanks for all your answers. This question is closed.

Comment: Try `file file.tar.xz`, this should give you a hint on the file type, unless it just says "data".

Comment: In addition to what Olaf Dietsche suggests, If this is a publicly available `.tar.xz`, can you give a link to it? What version of Ubuntu Mate are you running? Are you able to unpack the file with the Archive Manager (in MATE this is `engrampa` rather than `file-roller`)? What is the output of `apt list xz-utils`, of `xz --version`, and of `tar --version`? Please [edit] your question with all this information. Thanks!

Comment: "file.tar.xz: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines"  means you downloaded a website and NOT a file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
file.tar.xz: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
```

indicates that I downloaded a website. That's why it won't extract.

Comment: Indeed, the URL is not the direct address of the file, but that of a download page. You should download the file from a Web browser.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not download files from a random site. The contents of that file could have been altered to mess up you system.

The correct place to download from is the [debian wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/PepperFlashPlayer) and you download it from their [tracker site](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/pepperflashplugin-nonfree) and here is the [direct download](http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/contrib/p/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/pepperflashplugin-nonfree_1.8.1+deb8u1.tar.xz). It will download pepperflashplugin-nonfree_1.8.1+deb8u1.tar.xz and after downloading you can use your `tar` command to extract it.

To install though I would advice to use the normal Ubuntu installation. Enable "Canonical Partners" in Software & Updates and then run ...

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
```

This will install flash and the pepper flash plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the specified archive file was not downloaded correctly because of a certificate error. Remove `-q` from `wget` to see whether you might have the same problem.